# Using socat to use data coming from another machine

Tags: raspberry-pi, socat

I have a Raspberry machine running a program which process data coming from a /dev/ttyUSB0 device.
I want to move that device to another machine and transfer the data to the initial machine so it appears as coming from the original machine.
I feel that socat might be the answer but I am lost in the parameters of the command.
Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: post the socat syntax you are attempting with its output

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.
On the server side (were the physical device is plugged):

`sudo socat tcp-l:54321,reuseaddr,fork file:/dev/ttyUSB0,nonblock,b1200,cs7,parenb,waitlock=/var/run/ttyUSB0.lock`

On the client side (where the program is, expecting data from ttyUSB0):

`sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB0,wait-slave tcp:my_server_ip:54321`